# Multiple currencies in woocommerce not showing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I am newbie in Wordpress Plugin Development. I'm facing some issues. One currency payment displayed so how multiple currency payment will display.
Below code is showing one currency.

```
// Show product prices in fiat + crypto
function mcc_woocommerce_get_price_html( $text, $product )
{
    // Is MCC installed?
    if ( ! function_exists( 'mycryptocheckout' ) )
        return $text;
    // Retrieve all of our currencies.
    $currencies = MyCryptoCheckout()->currencies();
    // Change this to your preferred currency symbol
    $show_currency = 'BCH';
    $currency = $currencies->get( $show_currency );
    // Is this currency known?
    if ( ! $currency )
        return $text;
    $new_price = $currency->convert( get_woocommerce_currency(), $product->get_price() );
    return $text . ' / ' . $new_price  . ' ' . $show_currency;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'mcc_woocommerce_get_price_html', 100, 2 );
```

Comment: It is not clear what question you are asking. Please add detail to what problem you are facing so that we can help more easily. Wording your question like "[this] is happening, but I am expecting [that]" would help.